# What effects can apply to a creature inside a portable hole, from outside?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, planes

<sup>Related question: [Are you considered out of range of spells and weapons when inside the hole of a Portable Hole?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/125752/are-you-considered-out-of-range-of-spells-and-weapons-when-inside-the-hole-of-a)</sup>
(This question does not have an answer appropriate to the title. Also, the question only addresses weapons & spellcasting across the connection point; perhaps my question should be rephrased as
"What effects (if any) do *not* cross planar connections?" ?)

## What effects can apply to a creature inside a Portable Hole, from outside?

*If a kobold is standing just inside the edge of a P[ortable Hole](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/4699-portable-hole),

& is therefore on another plane, what effects (if any) can touch it?*

### What effects (if any) can reach across the planar connection?

Example scenarios, for all of which the same question applies:

- Can a character standing in the adjacent space directly outside the Portable Hole, use a weapon's *Reach* to hit the kobold with a Melee Weapon Attack?
- Can a character standing in the adjacent space directly outside the Portable Hole, hit the kobold with a Melee Spell Attack by casting *Inflict Wounds* with a range of Touch?
- Can a character standing in the adjacent space directly outside the Portable Hole, hit the kobold with a Melee Spell Attack by casting *Vampiric Touch* with a range of Self?
- Can a character standing 15 feet from the Portable Hole, target the kobold's space with *Bones of the Earth*'s AoE, to pinch the kobold between the pillar & ceiling?
- Can a character standing 15 feet from the Portable Hole, hit the kobold with *Fire Bolt* as a Ranged Spell Attack?
- Can a character standing 15 feet from the Portable Hole, target the kobold's space with *Flame Strike*'s AoE?
- Can a character standing 15 feet from the Portable Hole, target the space adjacent to the kobold which is just *outside* the Portable Hole, and hit the kobold with *Flame Strike*'s AoE?
- Can a character standing 30 feet from the Portable Hole, hit the kobold's space with *Fireball*'s AoE?
- Can a character standing 30 feet from the Portable Hole, target the space adjacent to the kobold which is just *outside* the Portable Hole, and hit the kobold with *Fireball*'s AoE?
- Can a character standing 30 feet from the Portable Hole, use the spell *Far Step* to teleport into the Portable Hole, within reach to hit the kobold with a Melee Weapon Attack?
- Can a character standing 15 feet from the Portable Hole, hit the kobold with an arrow from a *Bow*?
- Can a character standing 15 feet from the Portable Hole, throw an *Alchemist's Fire (flask)* into the kobold's space?
- Can a character standing 15 feet from the Portable Hole, cast *Spiritual Weapon* on a space inside the Portable Hole & adjacent to the kobold's space, to hit the kobold with a Melee Spell Attack?
- Can a character standing 15 feet from the Portable Hole, use the Trickery domain Cleric's *Invoke Duplicity* feature to project an illusory duplicate inside the Portable Hole & adjacent to the kobold's space, then cast *Spiritual Weapon* to hit the kobold with a Melee Spell Attack?
- If a character casts Hallow while standing in the center of the Portable Hole, do the effects extend outside the hole; & if so, what if the hole is moved afterward?
- If a character casts Hallow while standing in a space directly adjacent to the Portable Hole, do the effects extend inside the hole; & if so, what if the hole is moved afterward?

**In short, *do all effects other than those limited to a single plane, apply across planar connection points?* If not, which?**

Comment: I think the final question is fine, but most of the other question are of the form "Can I X someone inside a portable hole?" I think it shouldn't be hard for OP to consolidate the list into a few simple categories as either sub-questions or their own questions.

Comment: Upon further inspection, this looks like it’s probably a duplicate of the related question you linked.

Comment: I specifically selected as many *different* types of interaction, as possible. Even so, I left out spell sensors (because I expect uncertainty on that would muddy the question)... 

If one is to provide only a few examples of the question, which should I provide? 

The root question I suppose, is ***which*** of these effects can reach across the planar connection?

Comment: I voted to reopen, because even though the answers may be the same for both these questions, the question itself here is different in scope. It already had one reopen vote and directly reopened (normally, I think even for 5e where I have the gold badge, it only reopones immediately if there are no other votes yet? Not sure how that works).

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin If you have the gold badge for a tag, close/reopen votes are immediately effected. The only exception is if *you added the tag* that you have the gold badge for. In that case, your vote will be a normal one out of five vote.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov, thank you for the explanation, knowledgable as ever

Comment: @ThomasMarkov - I voted to reopen on [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/200657/75095) via the voting queue, and in this case, it counts my vote as a simple vote, in spite of the 5e tag (which I did not add). So I think the full rule of how this works must be that only if you vote reopen from the reopen link under the question, it is treated special if it has the tag, and you did not add it; if you vote from a queue, you have no special rights?

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin That question was not closed as a duplicate. It was closed for “off topic (other reason)”. The gold badge only applies to duplicate closures. I did not make that clear in my previous comment.

Comment: The duped question is asking the same thing - just in a different way. Both are asking about if you can target someone inside a bag of holding from spells or attacks. This is asking if spells or attacks an target someone. If you think the answers are missing something on the dupe target, I'd very much recommend adding a bounty to the question and describe what you think isn't answered.

Comment: Great answer there by Groody. Given the edits to that question, & the answer there, I'd consider this redundant now!